# libvirt - Restart VMs after return from power failure?

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, virsh, apcupsd

Is there any way to make KVM automatically restart any VMs that have been shut down due to power failure? Here is my scenario: I run a small VM tank, mostly with development VMs on it. I now have a VM that is set to autostart on system boot, which works. I have installed apcupsd on that VM, reading from the daemon on the host, and configured to shut down when battery reaches 75%. The host will shut down when the battery reaches 15%. My question is, if power returns during this window (i.e. the host stays up), can I restart the VM that was shut down? I know I could hard-code a call to 'virsh start [VM name]' but I am looking to start any VM flagged as 'autostart', somewhat like doing 'mount -a' to mount all defined filesystems. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

On my RHEL6 and CentOS6 that is established by creating a symbolic link to VM XML description in `/etc/libvirt/qemu/autostart/` :

```
ls -la /etc/libvirt/qemu/autostart/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Dec 19  2012 .
drwx------. 4 root root 4096 Dec 21 08:50 ..
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   29 Mar  3  2012 hosting2.xml -> ../hosting2.xml
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   43 May 25  2011 hosting.xml -> /etc/libvirt/qemu/hosting.xml
```

If you want to avoid setting up links manually: `virsh autostart <domain>`

> **`autostart [--disable] domain`**
>              Configure a domain to be automatically started at boot.